# Unable to disable the default login page in Spring boot 2.7.9 (Spring security 5.7.7)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-security

pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.9</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

MyReportsApplication.java

```
package com.karthik.reports;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyReportsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("IN MAIN CLASS");
        SpringApplication.run(MyReportsApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I have created a configuration class for custom security configuration as shown below

SecurityConfig.java

```
    package com.karthik.reports.config;
    
    @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsManager() {
        UserDetails user  = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
            .username("Karthik")
            .password("pass")
            .roles("ADMIN")
            .build();
        
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        System.out.println("SECURITY FILTER CHAIN");
        
        return http
                .csrf(csrf-> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.antMatchers("/country").permitAll();
                    auth.antMatchers("/state").hasRole("USER");
                    auth.antMatchers("/city/**").hasRole("ADMIN");
                })
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .build();
    }
}
```

When I hit my REST end point http://localhost:8090/myreports/country, I am getting a default login page. I have also enabled httpbasic authentication in the config class

Can you please advise on how to remove the default login page and why the default login form is coming for "/country" endpoint which need not be authenticated as per the config class.

Comment: You disabled security but haven't done anything to re-enable it. Either remove the exclude for the auto-configuration or add `@EnableWebSecurity` to your `@Configuration` class.

Comment: I annotated the config class with @EnableWebSecurity but still do not get the login page. The reason I disable the auto configuration is to use a custom login page.

Comment: You don't need to disable auto configuration for that, just provide the configuration for that.

Comment: I was not able to change the login page with default configuration on

Comment: I doubt that that is due to the auto configuration. Seems like your class is totally ignored. Is it in the right place?

Comment: My runner class is in com.karthik.reports whereas the SecurityConfig class is in the subpackage - com.karthik.reports.config

Comment: I see that, but is it in the correct source tree? DId you recompile? Do you even see the message you printed.

Comment: No, I dont the see the message printed. I suspect this config class is not getting picked up

Comment: Hence my question if it is in  the correct place and did you actually recompile it. If it is in `src/test/java` it won't be detected for instance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257252/discussion-between-karthik-and-m-deinum).